# Angular HttpPost executing twice in REST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

Have some problems with $HttpPost with angular that are executing it twice. 
For your info, the function is executed after returning promise from "getActiveSpools()" function. Somehow the "http://testserver/LitzMobileListener/LitzScannerService.svc/PostMfgoSetup/" is running twice that makes the data being uploaded twice.

I am new with angular and REST.

Your kind helps are really appreciated

```
$scope.getActiveSpools().then(function (promise) {

        $scope.spoolSetupHeader.STATUS = status;
        $scope.spoolSetupHeader.OPTR_IN = $rootScope.globals.currentUser.employeeId;
        $scope.spoolSetupHeader.PLANT_NO = $scope.spoolSetupHeader.setupMfgo.substring(1, 2);
        $scope.spoolSetupHeader.MFGO_NO = $scope.spoolSetupHeader.setupMfgo.substring(2, 9);

        $http({
            url: "http://testserver/LitzMobileListener/LitzScannerService.svc/PostMfgoSetup/"
            , method: "POST"
            , data: JSON.stringify($scope.spoolSetupHeader)
            , dataType: "json"
            , contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        }).then(function (result) {

            $scope.returnedStatus = new ReturnedOperationStatus();
            $scope.returnedStatus.IsSuccess = result.data.IsSuccess;
            $scope.returnedStatus.Message = result.data.Message;
            $scope.spoolSetupHeader = new OrderHeader();//new SpoolSetupHeader();
            $scope.spoolSetupHeader.PO_ID = result.data.RecordKey;
            $scope.spoolSetupHeader.ReturnedInfo = result.data.ReturnedObject;

            if ($scope.returnedStatus.IsSuccess == true) {
                alertTitle = "Success";

                //upload source wire if needed
                if ($scope.swNeeded == true) {

                    $scope.uploadMfgoSetupSpools('NEW', 'Active', true);
                }
                else {
                    $scope.uploadMfgoSetupSpools('UPDATE', 'Inactive', false);
                }

                //reload saved data
                $scope.getSetupMfgo($scope.spoolSetupHeader.PO_ID, 'DETAILS_ACT', null, null);

                //init new spool details list 
                //$scope.spoolSetupHeader.setupSpools = new Array();
                //myNavigator.pushPage('partial-setupSpool.html', { animation: 'slide' })

            }
            else {
                alertTitle = "Failed";
            }

            ons.notification.alert({
                message: $scope.returnedStatus.Message,
                title: alertTitle,
                modifier: true
            });
        });
    });//end promise
```

Comment: Me too, I had to wrap the call with a $timeout, and in the REST call on the server, I made sure to update only once, by checking a 'DONE' column in the data object updated (or you'll have to find some way to log/INSERT/UPDATE/WHATEVER, and then not performing the action if already done on the first call, by checking the log/DB).
Very dirty quick patch, but it works... You'll have more time to investigate on why it fires twice.

Answer (score 0):

I can't write comment so i will reply in answer. From my understanding, your http post request should run once. I don't have the chance to look but maybe in the

> $scope.getActiveSpools().then(function (promise)

call runs twice because of the $digest. You can look it from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest

This may lead you to the right answer. Sorry for not answering fully to your question.